# Angular/Typescript tsconfig.json configure path alias with multiple paths

Tags: angular, typescript, tsconfig

I configured some path alias in my `tsconfig.json` and they works fine:

```
"paths": {
  "@app/models": ["src/app/app.models"],
  "@app/routing": ["src/app/app-routing.module"],
  "@app/routing/*": ["src/app/routing/*"]
}
```

What I need now is to configure another path alias with multiple paths. Should be something similar to this:

```
"@app/ab": ["src/app/test-a/a", "src/app/test-b/b"]
```

The problem is when I import from `@app/ab` because I can see only classes declared in `src/app/test-a/a`. Is there a possibile solution to achieve this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could make an 'index.ts' file where you export "src/app/test-a/a", "src/app/test-b/b". And then refer to the index file.

// src/app/test-index.ts

```
export * from 'src/app/test-a/a';
export * from 'src/app/test-b/b';
```

// tsconfig.json

```
...
"@app/ab": ["src/app/test-index.ts"]
...
```

OR

Add the folders instead of the files

```
"@app/ab/*": ["src/app/test-a/*", "src/app/test-b/*"]
```

But then everything within 'test-a' and 'test-b' will also be exposed via that path.

Comment: This is a solution (I used this solution for `@app/models` alias that have about 20 paths) but to me it looks like a workaround in this specific case. Why should I need to create and extra file for two paths instead of simply add a value in array?

Comment: I've updated the answer. 
Check https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/module-resolution.html. The way you're trying to use it, the 2nd item in your path is a 'fallback'. It's not for single files, but for folders.

Comment: I understand. Thank you!